# Convert Object Fields to an Array of Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I am calling an authentication API that returns an `Observable<any>` where the object is:

```
name: "John"
role: "Admin"
```

The response can have a few variations:

1. Extra fields can be present;
2. If one field has more than one value than it returns an array:

   ```
   email: "john@example.com"   // 1. Extra Field 
   name: "John"  
   role: ["Admin", "Editor"]   // 2. Field now gets 2 values
   ```

I created an interface:

```
export class Claim {
  type: string;
  value: string;
}
```

How can I create an array of Claims from the object?

For the first example the array of Claims would be:

```
type      value
  
name      John
role      Admin
```

For the second example the array of Claims would be:

```
type      value 
  
email     john@example.com
name      John
role      Admin
role      Tutor         // An array would expand into multiple Claims of same type
```

**Update**

Following pc_coder answer I have the following:

```
getClaims(type: string): Observable<Claim[]> {

  return this.getUser().pipe(map(user => {

    let claims: Claim[] = [];

    Object.entries(user.profile).forEach((element)=>{ 
      if (typeof element[1] == "object") { 
        element[1].forEach(x => { 
          claims.push({ type: element[0], value: x })
        })
      }
      else { 
        claims.push({ type: element[0], value: element[1]})
      }   
    });

    return claims;

  }));

}
```

Should, or could, the transformation be made with RXJS operators?

And can I filter the claims by type in case `type` parameter of `getClaims` is not empty?

Comment: This doesn't look like the right approach. So if you could get it somehow working you might end up with `{ name: ['email', 'name', 'role', 'role'], value: ['john@example.com', 'John', 'Admin', 'Tutor'] }`. Which doesn't make whole lot of sense.

Comment: Type and Value are just the headers to explain what I mean ... Each row in the table is a Claim. So I would have an array of 4 claims. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` you can reach key names, then reach values. Check if value object or not then push to new object array

```js
var obj1={email: "john@example.com",name: "John" ,role: ["Admin", "Editor"] }
var obj2={email: "john@example.com",name: "John"  }

//with Object.keys
function convertTo(obj){
  var result=[];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((el)=>{
    if(typeof obj[el]=="object"){obj[el].forEach(x=>{result.push({type:el,value:x})})}
    else{ result.push({type:el,value:obj[el]})}
  })
  return result;
}
//with Object.entries

function convertTo2(obj){
  var result=[];
  Object.entries(obj).forEach((el)=>{ 
    if(typeof el[1]=="object"){ el[1].forEach(x=>{result.push({type:el[0],value:x})})}
    else{ result.push({type:el[0],value:el[1]})}   
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(convertTo2(obj1));console.log(convertTo2(obj2));console.log(convertTo(obj1));console.log(convertTo(obj2));
```

Comment: `Object.entries` might be better.

Comment: I am receiving an Observable and I need to return an Observable<Claim[]>. I have been trying to use Observable operators like map. Shouldn't that be the way?

Comment: Can you share your observable method and subscribe code also ?

Comment: Sure, I just added an update where I apply your code to the Observable. Shouldn't I use RXJS operators to to the conversion to Claims? And can I include a filter by type? Than you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function toClaims(data: {[key:string]: string|string[]}):Claim[]{
    const result=new Array();
    for(const type in data){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(type)){
            const element = data[type];
            if(Array.isArray(element)){
                for(const value of element){
                    result.push({
                        type,
                        value,
                    });
                }
            } else{
                result.push({
                    type,
                    value: element,
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am receiving an Observable and I need to return an Observable<Claim[]>. I have been trying to use Observable operators like map. Shouldn't that be the way?

Comment: You can do this.getUser().pipe(map(user)=>toClaims(user)). However, rxjs is not really for data transformation. It is more concerned with events. So, no, you cannot do this just by using rxjs operators.